# Checking if all factors within a factor are unique, then if so, returning that factor. If not, returning a third value. R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, factors

First time posting here! Been struggling with this for about two days but I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
code.1 <- factor(c(rep("x",3), rep("y",2), rep("z",3)))
type.1 <- factor(c(rep("small", 2), rep("medium", 2), rep("large", 4)))
df <- cbind.data.frame(type.1, code.1)
df
```

And am trying to get it to return this:

```
code.2 <- factor(c("x", "y", "z"))
type.2 <- factor(c("multiple", "multiple", "large"))
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(type.2, code.2)
df2
```

I've tried all manner of If/Else and apply functions grouping by "code" to return these results but am stuck. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `dplyr`: you group by `code.1`, then all you have to do is to summarize `type.1` with an if/else: if there is only a single value, you return it, else you return "multiple".

The code is slightly more complicated because of practical considerations (need to convert to character, need to have a vectorized TRUE condition that always returns a single value even when FALSE):

```
df %>%
  group_by(code.1) %>%
  summarize(type.2 = if_else(n_distinct(type.1) == 1,
                             as.character(first(type.1)),
                             "multiple"),
            type.2 = as.factor(type.2))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   code.1 type.2  
#   <fct>  <fct>   
# 1 x      multiple
# 2 y      multiple
# 3 z      large
```

EDIT: here is a different formulation of the same approach without converting to character, might be better suited for large problems, and might give a different view of the same question:

```
# default value when multiple
iffalse <- as.factor("multiple")

df %>%
  group_by(code.1) %>%
  mutate(type.1 = factor(type.1, levels = c(levels(type.1), levels(iffalse)))) %>% # add possible level to type.1
  summarize(type.2 = if_else(n_distinct(type.1) == 1,
                             first(type.1),
                             iffalse))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help @Alexlok!

Comment: @GregorThomas I don't think it works here: for example for `y` there are two separate values, so no duplicate, but we we want to count it as "multiple"; whereas with `z` we have a single value duplicated 3 times, so we keep this one. We would need a function "allDuplicated" (but where they are all the same duplicate). Apart from that, since `unique()` is also in C, do we expect such a big gain if we managed to get rid of it?

Comment: Ah, you're right. Think I didn't understand the problem well enough.

Comment: But, based on that, I think you can use `dplyr::n_distinct` as a drop-in for `nb_values` to avoid a custom function :)

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't find that function! I updated my answer.